# Ember Ember.Select binding

Tags: ember.js, ember.select

I am trying to create a simple page where I loop through a list of phone numbers associated with a Contact.  Each phone number has a "number" and a "phone_type".

I've created a View that extends Ember.Select that populates itself with a the list of phone_types.  Other than that, is's just a plain Ember.Select:

```
export default Ember.Select.extend({

        thestore: '',
        optionLabelPath: 'content.code',
        optionValuePath : 'content.code',

    didInsertElement: function() {

        var vtype = this.get("valuetype");

        var vls =  this.get("thestore").filter('valuelist', { type: 'phone_type' }, function(vv) {
             return vv.get("type") == vtype;
        });

        this.set("content",vls);
    }
});
```

Here is my code in the template using the "valuelist" view defined above.

```
    {{#each phonenumber in model}}
     <tr>
        <td>   {{phonenumber.number}}</td>
        <td>{{phonenumber.phone_type}}</td>
        <td>{{view 'valuelist' thestore=store  valuetype='phone_type' 
                selection="{{phonenumber.phone_type}}" 
                value="phonenumber.phone_type" }}</td>
     </tr>
{{/each}}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to bind the value in the dropdown to the field in each model record I am iterating through in the template.  You can see I've tried various things in the code above without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The property you need is `value`. However, in your attempts above, you were filling it with literal strings. This happens when you provide a value wrapped in quotes ('...' or "..."). What you need is to give it an `identifier`, which is value without quotes. So, try this:

```
{{#each phonenumber in model}}
 <tr>
    <td>{{phonenumber.number}}</td>
    <td>{{phonenumber.phone_type}}</td>
    <td>{{view 'valuelist' thestore=store  valuetype='phone_type' 
            value=phonenumber.phone_type }}</td>
 </tr>
{{/each}}
```

As an aside, this is a very unortodox way of doing things. A view shouldn't be tied to a store. Also, I think this will cause your select to be unusable while the values load asynchronously (and potentially crash your app if there is an error).

A conventional way to do this would be to load the list of all `phone_type`s in your `setupController` hook and then provide it as an argument to Select view.

**Controller:**

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  //...
  setupController: function (c, m) {
    c.set("model", m);
    c.set("phoneTypes", [
      "home", "office"
      // or whatever, load it from store in model hook and setup here
    ]);
  }
});
```

**Template:**

```
{{#each phonenumber in model}}
 <tr>
    <td>{{phonenumber.number}}</td>
    <td>{{phonenumber.phone_type}}</td>
    <td>{{view Ember.Select
          content=phoneTypes
          value=phonenumber.phone_type }}</td>
 </tr>
{{/each}}
```